# Протитип для обрезки символов до символа. ","

Tags: javascript, vue.js

)

Есть строка - например "Сегодня, я пойду"
Как написать метод, лучше Прототип для строк чтобы выводить текст до символа ","
В моём примере "Сегодня, я пойду" -> "Cегодня"

Заранее спасибо, всем позитива!)

Comment: А свои попытки решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю как-то так

```js
function getTillComma() {
    return this.split(",")[0];
}

String.prototype.tillComma = getTillComma;


console.log("Сегодня, я пойду".tillComma());

console.log("Сегодня не пойду".tillComma());
```

Comment: Не много не так, взять символы до ','

Comment: А я и взял символы до ","

Comment: В вашем примере должно выводить все символы до ',' тоесть 'Cегодня'

Comment: во втором случае запятой нет

Comment: ааа согласен )))

Comment: Оно и выводит в первом случае, во втором до запятой либо до конца

Comment: А как во Vue.js написать прототип и вызвать его с v-model="str.tillComma()" ?

Comment: Я не знаю как это реализовать для вашего примера. Но есть возможность такого рода https://blog.logrocket.com/accessing-properties-globally-in-vue-js-with-prototypes/

Comment: Думаю будет интересно как прототипирования во Vue метод и использовать его глобально в приложении

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115900/discussion-between-babakov-roman678-and-aziz-umarov).

Comment: я так сделал {{  city.split(',')[0]}}

Comment: Мне не понятно в чем проблема моего ответа так что вы сняли галочку

Comment: простите, уже поствил, ваш ответ мне помог! Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Патчить прототип String плохая идея, уже много раз писалось, что не надо заниматься манки патчингом. Что касается вашей задачи, то можно например так:

```js
const getWordBeforeComma = (str) => {
  const [word] = str.split(',');

  return word || '';
};
```

Comment: кстати, как сделать чтобы оно хранилось и старый массив? тоесть символы до обрезки ?

Comment: `[word, ...otherWords]`.